# How to override findAll() for Spring JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

I need to use a **@Query** annotation for **findAll()** method in my repository, which extends *JpaRepository*.

But I am getting the following error:
`"Not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNullApi"`

Here is my **repository**:

```
@Repository
public interface CommandInputRepo extends JpaRepository<CommandInput, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT DISTINCT columnA FROM tableA")
    List<Object> findAll();
```

After googling on StackOverFlow I have tried to create a **package-info.java** class, in which I defined 2 annotations: **@NonNullApi** and **@NonNullFields**.

**package-info.java**

```
@NonNullApi
@NonNullFields
package com.server.robot;

import org.springframework.lang.NonNullApi;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNullFields;
```

But the error doesn't disappear.

Do you know what else should I define or change?

Comment: try to  add  ```@NonNullApi``` above of your override method  that  is ``` findAll()```.